# Spring Security: redirect to a URL with path variable after successful login

Tags: spring, spring-security

The following is what I have to redirect a visitor to a page after successful login:

```
<bean id="authenticationSuccessHandler" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler" p:defaultTargetUrl="/account/quickview"/>
```

I would like to direct a visitor to a url with the following URL:

```
/account/quickview/id_of_account_object
```

How can I configure Spring security to append that account ID to the "/account/quickview" after successful login?

I am using Spring Security 3.1

Thanks and regards.

**Here is how I solved this**

I created a subclass of SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler and I added a property  called temporaryTargetUrl, which is set to "/account/quickview". When the class' onAuthenticationSuccess is called, I obtain the principal and the account id from the principal. At this moment, I append "/account_id" to temporaryTargetUrl and call the super:

```
super.setDefaultTargetUrl(this.temporaryTargetUrl + "/" + account.getId());
```

Note that getDetaulTargetUrl of SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler  is not available outside Spring's package, which is why I created temporaryTargetUrl in the first place.

Please feel free to comment.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can save the account ID into the spring security session object and retrieve the object when is called the quickview url.

to redirect to the url add into the bean customAuthenticationSuccessHandler the following property

```
<property name="authenticationSuccessHandler" ref="successHandler" />
```

and create the successHandler bean:

```
<bean id="successHandler" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler">
    <property name="defaultTargetUrl" value="/account/quickview" />
    <property name="alwaysUseDefaultTargetUrl" value="true" />
</bean>
```

regards

Comment: Thanks so much for your input. Could you please elaborate on "spring security session object and retrieve the object when is called the quickview url"? I am not sure about how to do it. I have been doing the rest in your post.

Comment: In my implementation, I only implemented "UserDetailsServiceImpl implements AuthenticationManager, UserDetailsService, ApplicationContextAware". In "UserDetailsServiceImpl", I have a method  loadUserByUsername.